# Como criar um estilo para ImageView no Android?

Tags: android, xml

Como criar um estilo formato para  `ImageView` passando para comprimento e altura nesse estilo para ele ficar "formatado" na tela?

Comment: Cara, não entendi muito bem sua pergunta. Tem como esclarecer melhor?

Comment: Poderia definir melhor **formatado na tela**? Você quer que ele respeite o tamanho da tela?

Comment: @ThiagoLuizDomacoski não isso, imagina um retângulo quero passar para essa `IamgeView` que fique com esse formato como as medidas especificadas no estilo

Comment: Isto você quer fazer via código?  Passar a altura e a largura no Java?

Comment: @ThiagoLuizDomacoski pode ser, mas eu estava penso em `xml` no `styles`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode especificar tamanhos fixos no arquivo `dimens.xml` que se encontra na pasta `res/values/`.

Para telas com mais de 820dp (telas de 7” e 10”)  você inclui no arquivo dimens.xml dentro da pasta `res/values-w820dp/`

Exemplo:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="@dimen/image_view_w"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/image_view_h”
...  
>
</ImageView>
```

dimens.xml:

```
<dimen name="image_view_w">55dp</dimen>
<dimen name="image_view_h">55dp</dimen>
```

Comment: @ThiagoLuizDomascoski vou testar primeiro, depois e eu marco como resolvido blz.

Comment: como passar esse comando via código?

Comment: **imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(R.dimen.image_view_w, R.dimen.image_view_h));**

Comment: mas ele mexe no tamanho da imagem e não imageView